# Problema con LOOP PL/SQL, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una consulta con PL/SQL la cual no he podido hacer marchar, la idea de esta consulta es poder recorrer (o comparar) las filas de una tabla dado los limites superiores e inferiores de la tabla es decir, por ejemplo: existe una tabla llamada "empleados", donde se almacenan (entre otras) el salario diario de c una persona (el cual puede variar segun el dia ) es decir en esta tabla tendremos para una fecha (20180701) un id de usuario y su paga diaria, la idea es que el administrador de la compañía introduzca el id del empleado y por el periodo de tiempo que quiere revisar (es decir, una fecha inicio y una fecha fin) para ese periodo la consulta debería ser capaz de decirle cuantas veces la diferencia de salario entre todos los días supero un umbral por ejemplo del 5%

A continuación el código en cuestión:

> (Es importante que tener en cuenta que por los momentos el codigo se ha limitado a comparar varios dias y mostrar unicamente la cantidad de veces donde la diferencia es superior a 5% o no)

---

```
DECLARE
u NUMBER :=0;
t NUMBER :=0;
r NUMBER :=0; 
k NUMBER:= 0;

FOR i IN 0... 5 LOOP 
u:= 0;
k:= k+2;
BEGIN  
(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - u, 'yyyymmdd')))a,
(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - k, 'yyyymmdd')))b,
IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) < 5%)
t:=t+1;
END IF;
ELSE IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) > 5%)
r:=r+1:
END IF;

u AS Veces_que_supero_5%,
t AS Veces_que_no_supero_5%

END LOOP
/
```

---

Al ejecutar el Script se obtiene el siguiente error:

```
ORA-06550: línea 6, columna 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "FOR" to continue.
ORA-06550: línea 6, columna 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + / at mod remainder rem .. <an exponent (**)> ||
   multiset
The symbol ".. was in
DECLARE
u NUMBER :=0;
t NUMBER :=0;
r NUMBER :=0; 
k NUMBER:= 0;

FOR i IN 0... 5 LOOP 
u:= 0;
k:= k+2;
BEGIN  
(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - u, 'yyyymmdd')))a,
(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - k, 'yyyymmdd')))b,
IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) < 5%)
t:=t+1;
END IF;
ELSE IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) > 5%)
r:=r+1:
END IF;

u AS Veces_que_supero_5%,
t AS Veces_que_no_supero_5%

END LOOP
```

---

Disculpe pero no entiendo porque mencionas el declare comparandolo con el for loop. Por otra parte, cambie el begin como sugeriste y el problema persiste adjunto el error

```
ORA-06550: línea 8, columna 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + / at mod remainder rem .. <an exponent (**)> ||
   multiset
The symbol ".. was inserted before "." to continue.
ORA-06550: línea 12, columna 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stdde
DECLARE
u NUMBER :=0;
t NUMBER :=0;
r NUMBER :=0; 
k NUMBER:= 0;

BEGIN 
FOR i IN 0... 5 LOOP 
u:= 0;
k:= k+2;

(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - u, 'yyyymmdd')))a,
(SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE FECHA = to_number(to_char(To_Date('20180809', 'yyyymmdd') - k, 'yyyymmdd')))b,
IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) < 5%)
t:=t+1;
END IF;
ELSE IF (Trunc (((b.salario - a.salario)/b.salario)*100, 2) > 5%)
r:=r+1:
END IF;

u AS Veces_que_supero_5%,
t AS Veces_que_no_supero_5%

END LOOP
```

Comment: Te indica en el error, `BEGIN` envuelve a todo el procedimiento, la estructura de los procedimientos o bloques anónimos en plsql es así `DECLARE (declara variables) BEGIN (haz algo) END;` en tu caso tienes el begin dentro de un for loop.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas crear un loop para resolver ese problema que pides.

Puede hacerlo tirando de las [`analytic functions`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) y realizar el cálculo directamente en un query. En este caso específico, la función [`lag`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) te devuelve el valor de una columna en la *fila anterior* del query. Con esto tienes todo lo que necesitas para hacer el cálculo.

Me es más fácil explicarlo con un ejemplo, así que mira este que he preparado para esta respuesta:

```
with
EmpleadoSalarioDiario as (
          select 101 idEmpleado, to_date('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') Fecha, 100.0 Salario from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 110 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 112 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 100 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 105 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 99 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 100 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 101 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 102 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 110 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 111 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 120 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-13', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 121 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-14', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 100 from dual
union all select 101, to_date('2018-01-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 106 from dual
)
select   a.*
       , lag(a.Salario) over (partition by a.idEmpleado order by a.Fecha) SalarioDiaAnterior 
       , abs(a.Salario - lag(a.Salario) over (partition by a.idEmpleado order by a.Fecha)) DiferenciaSalario
       , abs(a.Salario - lag(a.Salario) over (partition by a.idEmpleado order by a.Fecha)) / lag(a.Salario) over (partition by a.idEmpleado order by a.Fecha) * 100 DiferenciaPorcentualSalario
  from EmpleadoSalarioDiario a;
```

El resultado queda como sigue:

```
idE Fecha       Sal SlA Dif DifPorcentual
=== ========= ===== === === ========================================
101 01-JAN-18   100  -   -   - 
101 02-JAN-18   110 100 10  10
101 03-JAN-18   112 110 2   1.81818181818181818181818181818181818182
101 04-JAN-18   100 112 12  10.71428571428571428571428571428571428571
101 05-JAN-18   105 100 5   5
101 06-JAN-18   99  105 6   5.71428571428571428571428571428571428571
101 07-JAN-18   100 99  1   1.01010101010101010101010101010101010101
101 08-JAN-18   101 100 1   1
101 09-JAN-18   102 101 1   .9900990099009900990099009900990099009901
101 10-JAN-18   110 102 8   7.84313725490196078431372549019607843137
101 11-JAN-18   111 110 1   .9090909090909090909090909090909090909091
101 12-JAN-18   120 111 9   8.10810810810810810810810810810810810811
101 13-JAN-18   121 120 1   .8333333333333333333333333333333333333333
101 14-JAN-18   100 121 21  17.35537190082644628099173553719008264463
101 15-JAN-18   106 100 6   6
```

Ya con este resultado, es trivial obtener las filas (o contarlas) en las que la variación porcentual es mayor al 5%. Ese ejercicio queda para el lector.

Si no tienes Oracle a mano, puedes [encontrar y ejecutar el script directamente en liveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/g38w4agxw6havoxxyige8n17s)

Comment: Buenos dias, muchas gracias por su colaboracion la verdad (y como pudo haber notado) soy un programador inexperto. Una vez dicho esto, me gustaría comentarle lo siguiente: según entiendo la logica del codigo que me presenta  se limita a comparar unicamen un registro (fila) con el inmediatamente anterior, la forma que utilizó para asegurarse de que los salarios comparados correspondan con los del mismo empleado es agrupando los registros (en el select) por empleado y luego ordenandolos por fecha. Ahora bien la pregunta es: ¿Como haría para separar los resultados en función del idEmpleado?.

Comment: ¿Bastaría con incluir llamar los campos seleccionados en ese Select desde un Select externo? y (en el Select externo) ¿podría colocar los Case para contabilizar las veces que el salario supera el 5%?

Comment: La comparación ya está _separada_ por idEmpleado, se realiza con la clausula `partition by` de `over`. Esto significa que la información se _parte_ por idEmpleado y la función analítica actúa sobre cada partición (en este caso `LAG`)

Comment: Sobre tu última pregunta, podes valerte de un `CTE` o de una _tabla derivada_ para, sobre ella, aplicar un filtro (`where`) que te devuelva las filas que tengan porcentaje mayor a 5% y finalmente, contar estas filas, para lo que te vales de la función `count()`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Otra pregunta, si al Id del empleado tengo asociados 2 o 3 campos mas (por ejemplo horas trabajadas y cantidad de transacciones realizadas) y quisiera realizar quisiera contabilizar tambien estas diferencias ¿podría hacerlo bajo la logica que sugieres? en caso de que no pueda, ¿como me sugerirías abordar la situacion?

Comment: La puedes abordar utilizando la misma idea, incluso en la misma consulta.

Comment: Según entiendo bastaría con colocar:                                                
SELECT 
Count (b.DifPorcSal) AS "%DifPSal",
Count (b.DifPorchoras) AS "%DifPhtrab",
Count (b.DifPorchoras) AS "%DifPtransac"
(SELECT A.*,
/*OPERACIONES COMO LA DEL %*/
FROM EmpleadoSalarioDiario A;
)b
WHEN
WHEN                       
(b.DifPorcSal>5) OR
(b.DifPorchoras >10) OR
(b.DifPorchoras <10)

Comment: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Como podrás notar, el problema que se presenta al correr el script, por que en la condición "Cuando" 
incluyo a cualquier cosa que cumpla con alguna de las  3 condiciones (ya que estoy colocando "OR"), 
y como podrás intuir el valor almacenado en las 3 columnas resultantes (DifPSal - DifPhtrab - DifPtransac) 
será el mismo. Por otra parte, sí en el "Cuando" , coloco la condición "AND" solo me contara aquellos valores 
que cumplan con las 3 condiciones

Comment: Resulta muy difícil leer el código en comentarios. Considera la opción de editar tu pregunta para agregar información adicional a medida que avanzas con el problema, siempre y cuando eso no cambie el sentido de la pregunta original, o el publicar una nueva pregunta si ya ha quedado zanjado tu problema original y ahora te enfrentas a un nuevo problema (según me parece tu caso es este último).

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por su ayuda he colgado mi pregunta acá. Le comento esto en vista de que ud me ha ayudado mucho y es probable que me ayude a dar con el problema mas pronto de lo que quizá lo pueda hacer otra persona.                                                                                                https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190351/continuaci%C3%B3n-problema-pl-sql-oracle?noredirect=1#comment356632_190351                     Sauldos y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.
Veo varias inconsistencias en tu código, haces un bloque anónimo pero no veo que lo cierres, y los select's para obtener los datos, tampoco se ve donde se dejarán los valores (algún arreglo o tabla temporal?).

La solución que yo te sugiero es usar la función analítica **LEAD**, para mayor información puedes consultar la siguiente liga: [Función LEAD](http://psoug.org/definition/LEAD.htm)

Y haciendo unas suposiciones en base al código que incluyes, construí el siguiente código, inténtalo, solo reemplaza para el identificador del empelado en la tabla **EMPELADO_ID**:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1(EMP_ID NUMBER, FECHA_INI DATE, FECHA_FIN DATE) IS
    SELECT
      EMP.EMPLEADO_ID
      EMP.FECHA,
      EMP.SALARIO,
      /*Esta función agregada da el salario en n registros, si es un registro por fecha, o sea un pago por día por empleado, 
        entonces el resutlado es el empleado dado, los salarios de la fecha del registro y la columna salario_2 con el salario 
        del día siguiente, explicado cada parametro:
        LEAD ( --función que regresa valores hacia adelante
              EMP.SALARIO,  -- la columna a obtener el valor
              1,            -- número de registros hacia adelante según clausula OVER
              null)         -- si ya no hay más registros para adelante regresa el valor especificado aquí
         OVER (ORDER BY EMP.FECHA) -- En esta clausula se especifica como se va a ordenar el resutlado para obtener valores hacía adelante, en este caso es 1
        */
      LEAD(EMP.SALARIO,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY EMP.FECHA) AS SALARIO_2 
    FROM EMPLEADOS EMP
    WHERE
      EMP.EMPLEADO_ID = EMP_ID AND
      EMP.FECHA BETWEEN FECHA_INI AND FECHA_FIN;

  NEMP_ID NUMBER;
  DFECHA_INI DATE;
  DFECHA_FIN DATE;
  NVECES_SUP_5POR PLS_INTEGER;
  NVECES_NO_SUP_5POR PLS_INTEGER;
  FPOR_DIF NUMBER;
BEGIN

  NVECES_SUP_5POR  := 0;
  NVECES_NO_SUP_5POR := 0;

  --Empleado id
  NEMP_ID := 580;
  --rango de fechas
  DFECHA_INI := TO_DATE('20180801','YYYYMMDD');
  DFECHA_FIN := TO_DATE('20180810','YYYYMMDD');

  FOR C1REC IN C1(NEMP_ID, DFECHA_INI, DFECHA_FIN) LOOP
    FPOR_DIF := TRUNC(((C1REC.SALARIO_2 - C1REC.SALARIO)/C1REC.SALARIO_2)*100, 2);
    IF FPOR_DIF > 5 THEN
      NVECES_SUP_5POR := NVECES_SUP_5POR + 1;
    ELSE
      NVECES_NO_SUP_5POR := NVECES_NO_SUP_5POR + 1;  
    END;
  END LOOP;

END; --FIN DE BLOQUE ANONIMO
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.